# Save a file(zip) to specify folder in Android 10

Tags: android

I want create a file to specify folder ，my file type is zip，I want use
FileOutStream to create.

It sends an intent, you can see the code below:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)

startActivityForResult(mContext,intent, 9999,null)
```

then it gets the returned data, you can see the code below:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                9999 -> {
                    Log.v("Test", "Result URI " + data!!.getData())
//                    FileInputStream(data!!.getData())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the log is

> V/Test: Result URI content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATestFile

I want to create file with the Uri,but use FileOutStream will crash，have any way to create file in specify folder?

Comment: `want use FileInputStream to create.` You mean FileOutputStream. But as you use saf uries an OutputStream would do.

Comment: And have a look at DocumentFile.createFile().

Comment: Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` on the user's selected tree. Call `createFile()` on [that `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) to get a `DocumentFile` representing your desired content. Call `getUri()` on that `DocumentFile`. Use that `Uri` with a `ContentResolver` to write out content.